# Can't access model attributes with Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have a little problem with model attributes access with item/composite view.
In my ItemView, I have all models attributes data but when I want for example to output `<%=username%>` in my html/template nothing.

I don't know why this isn't working. Normally the code is as simple as mine.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/e6e68b525468606bd039 or below:

index.html:

```
<section>
  <%= test %>
  <ul class="thumbnails" id='userslist'></ul>
</section>

<script type="text/template" id="usertemplate">
  Username: <%= username %>
</script>
```

test.coffee:

```
define [ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'marionette', 'text!templates/us/index.html' ], ( $, _, Backbone, Marionette, TPL) ->

    class UserView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
        template  : '#usertemplate'
        tagName   : 'li'
        className : 'span2'

        initialize: ->
            console.log 'm:', @model.attributes

    class UsPageView extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
        template : _.template TPL
        itemView : UserView

        itemViewContainer: "#userslist"

        initialize: (options) ->
            @collection = options.collection
            @collection.fetch()

        appendHtml: (cView, iView, idx) ->
            cView.$(@itemViewContainer).append iView.el

        serializeData: ->
            test: 'ok'

    UsPageView
```

The console.log print: `Object { username: "Foo" }`

Comment: Are you actually able to console.log anything in the initialize method of ItemView?

Comment: Yes in every itemView initialize method I can access to all attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution:
- I create a new file with my template code:

```
  // --- members.html
  Username: <%= username %>
```

And I changed my ItemView class like this:

```
define [ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'marionette', 'text!templates/us/index.html', 'text!templates/us/members.html' ], ( $, _, Backbone, Marionette, TPL, M) ->

    class UserView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
        tagName   : 'li'
        className : 'span2'

        template: (serializedModel) =>
            _.template M, @model.toJSON()

    class UsPageView extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
        template          : _.template TPL
        itemView          : UserView    
        itemViewContainer : "#userslist"

        initialize: (options) ->
            @collection = options.collection
            @collection.fetch()

        appendHtml: (cView, iView, idx) ->
            cView.$(@itemViewContainer).append iView.el

    UsPageView
```

This solution work for me.
For my initial problem, it seems like is when I want to recup my template raw text. 
Normaly $('#usertemplate').text() return the template data with all '<%= ... %>' but no. 
I don't know why.

If someone find the solution I'm still interested :)